# How to set Client Certificate Passphrase in Intellij HTTP Client CLI

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ 'HTTP Client CLI' to invoke an endpoint that requires Client certificates. My setup is as follows

**Test.http**

```
### Dev Heath Check
GET {{host}}/path/
```

**http-client.env.json**

```
{
  "dev": {
    "host": "https://myApp.example.com"
  }
}
```

**http-client.private.env.json**

```
{
  "dev": {
    "SSLConfiguration": {
      "clientCertificate": {
        "path": "C:/HTTP_WS/certs/my.cer",
        "format": "DER"
      },
      "clientCertificateKey": {
        "path": "C:/HTTP_WS/certs/my.pem",
        "format": "PEM"
      },
      "hasCertificatePassphrase": true,
      "verifyHostCertificate": true
    }
  }
}
```

**Command to invoke 'HTTP Client CLI' is**

```
ijhttp -v http-client.env.json -p http-client.private.env.json -e dev test.http
```

and then I get following error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonObject
        at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsString(JsonElement.java:187)
        at com.intellij.httpClient.cli.HttpClientMain.loadEnvironment(HttpClientMain.kt:300)
        at com.intellij.httpClient.cli.HttpClientOptions.call(HttpClientMain.kt:186)
        at com.intellij.httpClient.cli.HttpClientOptions.call(HttpClientMain.kt:44)
        at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:1953)
        at picocli.CommandLine.access$1300(CommandLine.java:145)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2358)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2352)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2314)
        at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2179)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.execute(CommandLine.java:2316)
        at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2078)
        at com.intellij.httpClient.cli.HttpClientMain.main(HttpClientMain.kt:39)
```

Issue is *my.cer* and *my.pem* are password protected & I could not find any resource on jetbrains website that explains how to supply password for these in *http-client.private.env.json* or through any other CLI flag

If I were to use IntelliJ Idea Ultimate then option to supply password for these is available in editor's line gutter section for *http-client.private.env.json* file.

if anyone can help on how I can supply passwords in HTTP Client CLI, it would be a life saver.

Thanks for your time & help.

Comment: Please report an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA. It looks like a limitation of the command line HTTP client as the IDE version would ask for a password and save it in the IDE configured password manager. CLI version does not support that: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-260232/Add-password-to-SSLConfiguration#focus=Comments-27-4671675.0-0.